# Webpush notification link is not working in desktop

Tags: go, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this multicast FCM push notification which works fine to send notifications. The problem however is that the received notification does not open target link  (here `google.com`) in Desktop browser (tested on both Chrome and Firefox).

```
 func SendFCMNotification(title, body string, tokens []string) ([]string, error) {
        batchResp, err := fcm.SendMulticast(context.Background(), &messaging.MulticastMessage{
            Webpush: &messaging.WebpushConfig{
                Notification: &messaging.WebpushNotification{
                    Title: title,
                    Body:  body,
                    Icon:  "https://cdn2.somesite.com/heart.png",
                },
                FcmOptions: &messaging.WebpushFcmOptions{
                    Link: "https://google.com",
                },
            },
            Tokens: tokens,
        })

        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error sending multicast FCM notification: %w", err)
        }

        invalidTokens := []string{}
        for i, resp := range batchResp.Responses {
            if messaging.IsInvalidArgument(resp.Error) {
                invalidTokens = append(invalidTokens, tokens[i])
            }
        }
        return invalidTokens, nil
    }
```

I have looked at the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/tree/master/messaging/messaging.go#L664) and can not see any instructions that help me to resovle this issue, nor any working example elswhere of such deplyoment.

So how can I fix this?